# Unable to center a imageView in a tableView Footer

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, cgrectmake

I am trying to center a label and  an image in a tableView Footer

I can't seem to make it work for both device iPhone and iPad

Right now it is centered on the iPhone but that's because I hardcoded it.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    [lbl setText:@"Powered By"];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    District *school = [District new];

    UIImageView  * logoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 25, 150, 37.5)];
    logoView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];

    [logoView autoresizingMask];
    [view addSubview:logoView];

    [view addSubview:lbl];

    return view;
}
```

I would like to center this view, without hardcoding it. I tried taking the screen size and divide by 2.

It did not center, what is the right approach, please advise.

Comment: You need to set the label's and image view's `autoresizingMask` properly.

Comment: I read this in one answer, I did not know how to add it, can you please show me, the label is above the image and both should be centered

Comment: try to set `logoView.center = view.center;` moreover remove `[logoView autoresizingMask];` it is a getter and you do nothing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the view's `autoresizingMask` as needed.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    CGRect lblFrame = view.bounds;
    lblFrame.origin.y = 15;
    lblFrame.size.height = 20;
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblFrame];
    lbl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    [lbl setText:@"Powered By"];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    District *school = [District new];

    CGRect logoFrame = CGRectMake((view.bounds.size.width - 150) / 2.0, 25, 150, 37.5);
    UIImageView  * logoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:logoFrame];
    logoView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];

    logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [view addSubview:logoView];

    [view addSubview:lbl];

    return view;
}
```

This assumes the label should fill the width and the image should stay centered left-to-right.

Comment: what about setting center for logoView? wouldn't that work and be easier?

Comment: @JulianKról That would work initially but you still need to set the `autoresizingMask` properly to ensure the image view stayed centered as its parent view's size changed.

Comment: okay, then yours is easier - one line of code less :) what about using autolayout? shouldn't that be a path to follow?

Comment: Thanks a lot rmaddy , how can I practice programmatically creating views, its a dark aspect of ios to me. any idea

Comment: @WarehouseMuzik By doing it. I'm the opposite. Storyboards and Interface Builder confuse me to no end. I do everything in code because it's easy and there's no mystery going on.

Comment: I think you right I tend to use the code only when I cannot do it in the storyboard, which shows that is superior